# Show checkers while editing transparent document

Tags: inkscape

I'm creating a **transparent document with some white elements** on it.

The default behaviour of Inkscape for my document is to show the content white on white
so I can not see anything.

My current workaround is to change the document background (File > Document Properties > Page > Background) to e.g. grey, then edit the document - now everything is shown as white on grey.

Then I need to change the document background back to transparent before every PNG export. (File > Export Bitmap)

Is there a trick to change the background of editing area of Inkscape? Checkers would be ideal. Did not find suitable setting in
Inkscape 0.47 on Ubuntu Linux 10.04 yet.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround was suggested on the [InkscapeForum](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5262):

- create an additional layer
- fill it with a pattern
- bring it to the bottom
- lock it
- work on layers above it
- hide it on every export, unhide again